# I have to create a group in yammer using JavaScript

Tags: yammer

I have to create a group in yammer using JavaScript or using any other services so we can call that service from AJAX. For that group i can give my own name,number of users and mainly i can get that group ID.
Please Help Me.

Comment: the api doesn't allow creating groups

Answer (score 0):

Like atmd said there doesn't seem to be any API for creation of Yammer-groups.

There are, however, endpoints for joining/leaving groups;

```
POST https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/group_memberships.json?group_id=:group_id

DELETE https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/group_memberships.json?group_id=:group_id
```

wich in turn are joining and leaving.

[Source](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/176/t/196949.aspx)

Comment: Hi binusr,     
As per our requirement we have to create group using JavaSript.
Please Help me for the same

Comment: Hi Santhosh, there isn't a supported way to do this programatically. Group creation is a manual activity in Yammer. Even if you find an unsupported endpoint that allows this to happen, your code will break in the future, the API changes a lot.